# CoffeeScript methods as D3js callbacks

Tags: d3.js, callback, coffeescript

I just stepped on this bug (or maybe it's a "feature")

If I pass a bound method (defined with fat arrow) as a D3js callback, it gets called with null arguments:

```
d3.json "some.json", @handler
```

If I enclose it in a bound closure (fat arrow) then it receives its arguments ok:

```
d3.json "some.json", (json) => @handler json
```

[Here is a JSFiddle showing the issue.](https://jsfiddle.net/16po2m61/)

Passing fat-arrow bound methods as standard Javascript callbacks (eg. to `setTimeout`) or as jQuery callbacks or event handlers is a proven technique, in fact I have an entire application written this way.

Why is it not working in D3js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the callback for `d3.json` has two arguments (see [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_json)):

> [T]he callback is invoked with two arguments: the error, if any, and the parsed JSON.

If D3 detects that the callback function has only one argument, it only passes the data, but it can't do that in your first example. Changing the definition of the handler function accordingly fixes the issue:

```
directHandler: (e, x) =>
    @log "directHandler received #{JSON.stringify x}"
```

Complete demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/16po2m61/1/).